# Помогите решить простые палиндормы?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Не могу написать код, который успеет выполниться за время.
код и скрины далее:

```
program ex;
var  i,k,n,count: word;
z,err:integer;
function dec2bin(x:integer):string;
var s:string;
begin
s:='';
while x>0 do
begin
 s:=chr(ord('0')+x mod 2)+s;
 x:=x div 2;
end;
dec2bin:=s;
end;
function palindrom(var a:integer):integer;
var b,c:integer;
begin
b:=a;
c:=0;
while b>0 do
begin
c:=c*10+(b mod 10);
b:=b div 10;
end;
if c=a then palindrom:=1
   else  palindrom:=0;
end;
begin
readln(n);
for k := 1 to n do begin
count := 0;
for i := 1 to k do begin
if k mod i = 0 then inc(count)
end;
if count = 2 then (*write(k, ' ')*)
              begin
              val(dec2bin(k),z,err);
              if (palindrom(z)=1) then
              writeln(k);
              end;
end
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему на даном сайте тему палиндромов изучили вдоль и поперек. Полистайте вопросы поиском либо переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Алгоритм не тот.

Answer (score 1):

Приведённый алгоритм квадратичен, т.е. время его работы пропорционально n^2, что для олимпиадной задачи с указанным ограничением n=10^6 неприемлемо.

Более выгодно не проверять все числа подряд, а просто сгенерировать все бинарные нечетные палиндромы

```
  чётная длина
1 110 + 011 1 = 1 110011 1
  нечетная длина
1 10 + 0 + 01 1
1 10 + 1 + 01 1
```

и проверить их на простоту. Этих палиндромов будет всего порядка тысячи